# find second match value in bottom up table (Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel I want to use an array formula that automatically shows the 2nd relative value of a vlookup criteria.

I managed to do this in a top-down list, where I add data on top. But am unable to get this working in a bottom-up list.

I [visualized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6R7P.jpg) the question for your convenience...

[image]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happen if you simply change that `SMALL` to `LARGE`?  Does that give you the answer you are expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went a different route than what you did. Type the following array formula into cell F2. (I included a line break for readability.)

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(LARGE(((A2=A$2:A$11)+0)
*((ROW()>ROW(A$2:A$11))+0)*ROW(A$2:A$11),1),COLUMN($A2)+1)),"-")
```

[image]

Comment: this returns `-` for cell F2, and `bad` for the rest

Comment: You have to enter it as an array formula. (Press Ctrl+Shift+Enter.) See above, I edited my post to include a picture of the correct results.

Comment: Indeed Peter, thanks. Do you recon that your solution will be more processor friendly for large list (compared to the solution that uses the index-function)?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. If you have a large sheet, I would just try both formulas and see which one is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Switching `SMALL`to `LARGE` did it.

The formula of cell F7 should be:

```
INDEX($B$1:B6,LARGE(IF($A$1:A6=$A6,ROW($A$1:K6),""),2),1)
```

More info can be found in Patrick G. Matthews's ["Finding the Nth Lookup Value in an Excel List](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/10590/Finding-the-Nth-Lookup-Value-in-an-Excel-List.html).